# Best Visual SharePoint 2007 Workflow Builder

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, workflow

We have a number of database driven apps we'd like to build out within SharePoint 2007 (the data will need to stay within SQL Server and not SharePoint).  Can anyone recommend some robust visual tools that support doing this within SP 2007, but also allow for business rules such as "if the user is in this group then they can see this, if they database value = this then show this, but not this and don't let them edit this."

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with workflow? Also, had you considered using Visual Studio with the add-on for SharePoint development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a job for Forms based authentication here (SqlMembershipProvider), combined with audiences / SP usergroups. Most can be done through the Web UI... Not really seeing the relation to workflows here.